# why 'fancybox-overlay' div doesn't have 'display: block' as inline style?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

```
<a href="img/blog-img-01.jpg" class="single_image">
   <div class="blog-img-wrap">
     <img src="img/blog-img-01.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</a>
```

fancybox css, js files are from cdn.

Answer (score 0):

With fancybox (either version 1 or 2) and any other popup e.g Bootstrap Modal, jQuery dialog Modal where hidden element can be shown with jQuery, JS or Pure CSS, the main hidden selectors always have property `display: none` to hide them; In this case fancybox which is

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none; <---Here
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url(background.png);
}
```

and to show the hidden element, **By Default** jQuery, JS **over-ride** the hidden selector property `display:none;` to `display:block;` to make then visible

[image]

In this case (Fancybox v2) You can use custom script to override the default behavior of jQuery `display:block;` to `display:inline;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers : {
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'display' : 'inline',
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/12732/)

[image]

And answer of your question

*why 'fancybox-overlay' div doesn't have 'display: block' as inline style?*

Because it's has nothing to do with fancybox, It's jQuery default behavior to show hidden element with property `display:none` by over-riding with property `display:block`